# On click find index of parent element (not clicked element)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the index of the .closest element to the clicked element. My function works to find which button is clicked, but I need to find the index of the parent element.

The problem is not all of my parent elements contain this button. This is my code so far:

```js
var clickCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".click-check");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(clickCheck, function (checkC, index) {
    checkC.addEventListener('click', function () {
     console.log("Clicked button " + index);
         checkC.closest(".check-parent");
        })
});
```

```css
.check-parent {
 background-color: #EC008C;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

.click-check {
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="check-parent">
 <div class="element">
  <div class="click-check">Klik hier</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="check-parent">
 <div class="element">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="check-parent">
 <div class="element">
  <div class="click-check">Klik hier</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that when the second parent element with class `check-parent` doesn't contain the button, it's index is skipped. I'm thinking I can use this part `checkC.closest(".check-parent");` to maybe find like a nodeList and then find the length or something?

When I click the second button (in third parent) the console logs index 1 (which is logical). How do I find the index of the parent element here? So i want it to show index 2 instead of index 1.

Comment: Try this...


var clickCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".check-parent");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(clickCheck, function (checkC, index) {
    checkC.addEventListener('click', function () {
     console.log("Clicked button " + index);
        })
});

Comment: Updating your querySelectorAll function to check 'check-parent' instead of 'click-check' solves both your issues.

Comment: Yeah I simplified my html here, but the real page has a lot more children and all sorts of buttons and clickable elements. That's why I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Is this implementation fulfill the requirement.

```js
var clickCheck = document.querySelectorAll(".click-check");

Array.prototype.forEach.call(clickCheck, function (checkC, index) {
      checkC.addEventListener('click', function () {
         console.log("Clicked button " + checkC.closest(".check-parent").getAttribute("data-index"));
         ;  
       })
     
});
```

```css
.check-parent {
 background-color: #EC008C;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 margin: 10px 0px;
}

.click-check {
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="check-parent" data-index="0">
     <div class="element">
        <div class="click-check">Klik hier</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="check-parent" data-index="1">
     <div class="element">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="check-parent" data-index="2">
     <div class="element">
        <div class="click-check">Klik hier</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really, because I can't make the parent element clickable. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue another way.

I added data-index to `<div class="check-parent">` like `<div class="check-parent" data-index="0">` and then I used `checkC.closest(".check-parent").getAttribute("data-index");` to gain the index of the parent.

Thanks for your suggestions!